# htmlentities not working on single quote

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to do a simple convert of single quote (`'`) to html entity (`&#39;`) but can not figure out why this is not working.

```
$test = "Bob's House";

echo htmlentities($test,ENT_QUOTES);

echo htmlspecialchars($test,ENT_QUOTES);
```

Both examples still return: Bob's House

I have tried a combination of flags: ENT_IGNORE, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, etc with no success.

I suspect it has something to do with my charset. If so how do I display my default charset & alter it for this seemingly simple code to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working. You are outputting `Bob&apos;s House` (or similar).

But since you're in a browser, it sees the `&apos;` and replaces it with `'`.

Want proof? Right-click and View Source.

More proof? `echo strlen($test) . " -- " . strlen(htmlentities($test,ENT_QUOTES));`

Comment: By the way, how do I display my default charset?